# setInterval in a promise, only executes once in React

Tags: reactjs, promise, setinterval

I'm trying to create a countdown timer with one second ticking away each second. The interval works only one time and does not execute. The problem is that I do not have *this.state.timetill until a server call is made*, then I can begin the timer. Therefore, the setInterval function has to be tucked away in a promise, where it executes only one. The timetill variable however can be a constant, once retrieved it does not change.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
const that = this;
*do stuff*
this.someFunction().finally(() => {
/*This right here, below is not working */
setInterval(that.createTimer(), 1000);  
});
}
```

My JSX is such

```
{this.state.setTimer}
```

function in question, the time has to be divided by 1000 since javascript uses miliseconds

```
createTimer = async timerNow => {
var timerNow = (await new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distance = this.state.timeTill - timerNow;
// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
//the variable displayed
var setTimer = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
this.setState({setTimer});
};
```

Comment: whts the exact issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the returned value of `createTimer` to `setInterval`, instead pass the function but don't invoke it

`setInterval(this.createTimer, 1000)`

Comment: So I can see the setInterval working but for whatever reason it's not updating the frontend or the state of the variable.

Comment: @NikLoladze You don't update the state inside `createTimer`?

Comment: I do and when I set the state to a variable such as timerNow, it will update accordingly. But for whatever reason, when I set it to the string, SetTimer, it will not update. I thought perhaps it was too computationally heavily and set the timer to five seconds, still no difference.

Comment: @NikLoladze You need to call `this.setState` from the interval callback, also you can't return the value of `setInterval` callback, instead of `returning setTimer` call `this.setState` with the new timer

Comment: In turns out, it's the math related to the seconds. Can you explain briefly why your answer worked? Thanks.

Comment: @NikLoladze No problem, I don't think there is much to add, `setInterval` expects a function as an argument but you passed the returned value of that function by invoking it `func()` instead of `func`. You can't return anything from the callback so you need to update the state from inside the interval callback. also Mor's answer included some useful suggestions, might want to apply them as well

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you should do:
1. Have a method that will actually call `setState`
2. Change `setInterval` to call a method *reference*
3. Cleanup any pending request on unmounting:
4. [optional] you can drop `that`

```
private createTimer = { ... }

private setTimer = () => {
  this.setState({ timer: this.createTimer() });
}

private _mounted: boolean = false;
private _intervalHandler: number | null = null;

componentDidMount = async () => {

  this._mounted = true;

  this.someFunction().finally(() => {
    if (!this._mounted) { return; }

    this._intervalHandler = setInterval(this.setTimer, 1000);  
  });
}

componentWillUnmoun = () => {
  this._mounted = false;
  if (this._intervalHandler !== null) {
    clearInterval(this._intervalHandler);
  }
}
```

This will ensure you are not performing state changes after the component was unmounted.